# JQueryUI Slider initial value go to the max

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, slider

I have several sliders in my page, and I create them like:

```
$(".slider").each(function () {
            var actualVal=$(this).attr("data-val");
            var maxVal=$(this).attr("data-max");

            $(this).slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 1,
                animate: true,
                max: maxVal,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    //Action 1...
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    //Action 2...
                },
                value: actualVal,
            });
        });
```

The problem is that very often the slider go to the maximum value, and not to the value that I initially define.

Does this appened to anybody?

I've allready tryed to call initially:

```
$(this).slider("destroy");
```

Comment: It appens in JSF inside Ajax content and with values greater than 10... WTF!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I finnally found the problem... I'm getting the value through a Attribute, and the value was treated not as Integer...

Making it as integer with ParseInt worked just fine...